# how to fix Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in this specefic line of code

Tags: php

this are codes which might have problem ' how I can solve it?

```
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_title()); ?>">


<?php echo wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_title()); ?></a></h3><hr />
```

Comment: Which specific line of code? You've posted two. They both call get_the_title() - is that the problem? If it is in core code, do you have a call stack that shows which line of code that's on? Are you using the latest code, 5.4.2?

Comment: There's nothing in this code that would cause this error. Are you certain these are the lines? Also, `wp_strip_all_tags()` is not sufficient to escape a value for the `title` attribute. Use `the_title_attribute()`.